# Make Whole Request UTF-8 from NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, json, utf-8, nsurlsession

I am making a simple NSURLSession GET request and i am returned the right data and i am able to serialize it up to one point where the data is no longer UTF-8 so i am unable to call keys of the children.

My data looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "GeoJsonData":"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-119.1968536376953,35.5229358991794],[-119.19696092605591,35.52019399894053],[-119.19206857681274,35.520141605030304],[-119.19204711914062,35.52003681710729],[-119.18736934661865,35.52007174643016],[-119.18730497360228,35.52213254957543],[-119.18839931488039,35.52215001378275],[-119.18842077255249,35.522813650845336],[-119.19696092605591,35.522918435143076]]}}",
  "GeoJsonCenter":"{\"lat\":35.52148635814335,\"lng\":-119.1921329498291}"
 },
 {
  "GeoJsonData":"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-112.42687225341795,33.49409462250672],[-112.42678642272949,33.47605511894646],[-112.42549896240234,33.47605511894646],[-112.42103576660156,33.48822503770075],[-112.41022109985352,33.49438093353938],[-112.42687225341795,33.49409462250672]]]}}",
  "GeoJsonCenter":"{\"lat\":33.48521802624292,\"lng\":-112.41854667663574}"
}
]
```

As you can see there are alot of escape characters in there and i have 85 objects in this array i need to iterate over and once i get down to the children of these objects i am not able to call those objects.

example of my code:

```
     NSMutableArray *geoJSONData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *item in jsonArray){
       [geoJSONData addObject:[item objectForKey:@"GeoJsonData"]];

    }

   for (NSDictionary *item in geoJSONData) {

  NSLog(@"%@", [item objectForKey:@"coordinates"]);
                                          }
```

the last NSLog blows up the console because it is not able to find that key "coordinates" because it is wrapped with escaped characters and i need to get those out.

Has anyone ran into this issue and whats the best way to solve this so i can have my object working fully serialized as JSON.

any help is greatly appreciated, im just getting back into Objective-c from AngularJs and last time i worked with Objective-C i used NSUrlRequest...so things have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data that you shown is the real representation of it then you have a small issue. The value for key `GeoJsonData` is not an object but a string. In other words it's an object that was serialized using JSON.stringify() and added to the parent object. Quite a strange construction, that's why I'm asking if that is the real JSON representation sent by the server.

What you'll need to do before trying to access the key `coordinates` is to JSON parse that string to get a valid object back so you can access it's properties as a normal NSDictionary, write now is just a string.

Just use NSJSONSerialization class to decode your `GeoJsonData`.

Comment: you were right, it is a string and thats real JSON coming back from the server. Turned out to be an error on at the API level.